Godot shader face culling
I have a torus mesh instance and this shader applied 
shader_type spatial;

uniform sampler2D color_tex;

uniform float speed : hint_range(0.0, 1.0) = 0.005;

void vertex() {

}

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = texture(color_tex, mod(UV + TIME * 2.5 * speed / 10.0, 0.0)).rgb;
    ALPHA = 1.0;
}

This results in

But if I look from the different angle then it looks like:

I tried different render_modes: cull_disabled, cull_front, cull_back, unshaded - nothing helps. 
I am using Godot 4.3 on Ubuntu.
Is it something I miss? Will be grateful for any help. 
